# WPF StaticResource for width

Tags: wpf

```
<Style x:Key="Small" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
</Style>    

<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyleSmall" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource Small}" />
</Style>
```

I get the error

> System.Window.Style is not a valid value for the System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Width property on a setter

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning a Style to a property, not to the control that has that property. Since you apparently want to use the value in a Style, it can't be a Style itself - it has to be of the same type as the target property, i.e. a `Double`:

Define the `system` namespace

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

And define `Small` as a `Double`, not a `Style`:

```
<system:Double x:Key="Small">80</system:Double>
```

---

Also, keep in mind that this will only work if the button doesn't have a `Width` set because local values (e.g. `Width="Auto"`) take precedence over style values.

Comment: Thanks, that does it!